# Prevent unchecked changes from merging into main branch

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

We have a PL/SQL (Oracle DB procedural language, but it doesn't really matter) git project. We have `develop` branch that holds all changes and appears to be PRO current state (though it should've been better to use `master` instead but it's been for years). We usually create branches from `develop`, do some changes to this branch (assume, it's `feature/JIRA-1234`). Then we have env-branches that represent state of QA, Integration, UAT testing envs (assume, it's one of them and it's `env/qa`). We merge ready-to-be-tested features into desired env branches. After testing we create release branch that collects all the features which are ready to be deployed in PRO. We check deployment on stage env, fix installation problems if any and then tag the latest commit of this branch with release tag and pass it to OPS team which takes care of deployment process.

A problem we're facing now with such approach is that `feature/JIRA-1234` branch remains "unprotected" after merging to `env/qa`, `env/uat`, etc up to the moment of merging to a release branch. So I can pass a branch to a QA team after having 6 commits there and push something new to this branch and then pass it to `env/uat`, for instance, and later even make changes before it will be merged into release branch. So after some time QA engineer can't really say that he/she tested the *latest* version of the branch.

I thought of maybe somehow "locking" the feature branch from merging before some event happens (like "QA passed"). Or maybe change development process. Sometimes developers want to improve their code by adding a *small little fix that really shouldn't be tested* but later it turns out to be a bug in PRO.

We are using gitlab as a tool for reviewing and managing merge requests. So possibly it has some tools for solving this puzzle but I haven't managed to find it so far.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Or maybe you can share links with articles that cover such situations.

EDIT:

I'm aware of `git flow` approach. I don't think that it works for us as we can't merge features back to `develop` as a scope of the upcoming release is uncertain till some moment in time. So my tested feature couldn't get into a release just because biz team doesn't want to see it in PRO by now. That's why we don't have `develop` branch in terms of `git flow` approach.

Comment: It seems like you just don't have the right branches and the right rules for what they can merge to... Look into `git flow` ... https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: @JoelFan hi! thanks for pointing out. I've put my thoughts in EDIT.

Comment: I don't understand why `git flow` wouldn't work.  `develop`, `release` and `master` are 3 different branches.  Do you have these 3 branches (even if you give them another name)?.  In the scenario you described ("biz team doesn't want to see it in prod"), your tested feature could be merged into `develop` but not into `release`.  There is NO "merging `develop` into `release`" in `git flow`. Rather, `release` *branches out* from `develop` at the desired commit (not necessarily from the *latest* commit) in `develop`.  You may just need to really learn `git` better.

Comment: @JoelFan thanks for explanation! Assume we have 4 tested features merged into `develop` in the following order: `f/1`, `f/2`, `f/3`, `f/4`. And we decided to create a release with features `f/1` and `f/3`. I can fork from `f/3` commit but how can I exclude `f/2` from it?

Comment: First of all the fact that f/2 and f/4 were merged into develop was a mistake.  You should not merge a feature into develop until you're sure you want it in the next release. If you have already merged them, you can revert the unwanted merge commits from develop, then create a release branch after the revert commits.  If you want QA to test features that are not going into the next release (a questionable goal), then create a new "qa" branch that has all the "ready for testing" features in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JoelFan I finally got understanding of working with branches.

Also after some googling I found out that except [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) process there exists [github-flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) and [gitlab-flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html).

The first one is quite simple and applicable for a small and quick-to-roll-out releases while the second one offers an approach for SAAS-like products which have env-dependent branches. I think it will be useful for our releasing model with some additional tweaks.